OAuth + react + Spring -> POST http://localhost:3000/google-login 404 (Not Found)
I was implementing the login part using spring + react + oauth, but an error occurred.
I don't know what's wrong with my code.. please help me
`import Axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login';
Now, in Login.js, Isn’t this how you bring it? Why does the 404 error keep showing up? 
let jwtToken = await Axios.post(
      'http://localhost:8000/google-login',
      JSON.stringify(postData);
      config
    ); 

App.js
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    },
};

const responseGoogle = async (response) => {
    try {
        console.log('Google Login Response:', response);

        // Prepare data to send to the server
        const postData = {
            tokenId: response.tokenId, // Use the tokenId received from Google
        };

        // Send a POST request to your backend
        let jwtToken = await Axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8000/google-login', // Make sure this URL matches your backend endpoint
            JSON.stringify(postData),
           config
       );

         // Check the response from the server and save the JWT token if successful
        if (jwtToken.status === 200) {
            console.log('JWT Token:', jwtToken.data);
            localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', jwtToken.data);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Google Login Error:', error);
    }
};

const Login = () => {
    return (
        <GoogleLogin
            clientId="1054743034506-atjsapju5vt05ugd9oesgdi2mqqq5cir.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            buttonText="Login"
            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
            onFailure={responseGoogle}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
        />
    );
};

export default Login;`

Login.js
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './Login';

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [jwtToken, setJwtToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'));

  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwtToken,
    },
  };

  // to retrieve user information
  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/user', config); // Change to backend address
      setUser(res.data); // 서버에서 받은 사용자 데이터 설정
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to retrieve user information:', error);
    }
  };


  // Login process
  const handleLogin = (token) => {
    setJwtToken(token);
    localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
  };

  // Logour process
  const handleLogout = () => {
    setJwtToken(null);
    localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
    setUser(null); // After logour reset
  };

  // Get user information on page load (if token exists)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (jwtToken) {
      getUser();
    }
  }, [jwtToken]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Login onLogin={handleLogin} />
      {jwtToken ? (
        <div>
          <h1>/user : {user ? user.username : 'No user information'}</h1>
          <button onClick={getUser}>Get user information</button>
          <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
          <button onClick={fetchData}>Get backend data</button>{' '}
          {/* fetchData function call button */}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Login is required</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Error message is here
Login.js:21 
 POST http://localhost:8000/google-login 404 (Not Found)
Login.js:33 Google Login Error: 
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61:1)


It shows your server is running and accepting HTTP request but cannot find the routing, please share snippets from your server implementation and enrich your question to get better feedback.

You should not be getting tokens from the browser.
Instead, use the OAuth2 BFF pattern. This is an article I wrote, which contains a React frontend connected to a Spring Backend and authenticating users on an OIDC authorization server.
